# DOM Exception 11 InvalidStateError with webkitEnterFullscreen()

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, html5-video, fullscreen

I'm using Chrome and my HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var vid = document.createElement('video');
            vid.src = "small.mp4";
            document.body.appendChild(vid);
            vid.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
                vid.webkitEnterFullscreen();
            });
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting an error on vid.webkitEnterFullscreen();

Comment: Maybe you need to check whether your chrome supports full screen ("vid.webkitSupportsFullscreen"), before call "webkitEnterFullscreen()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to enter fullscreen on a 'loadedmetadata' event. You have to wait for a click/keypress event.

```
window.onload = function() {
        var vid = document.createElement('video');
        vid.src = "small.mp4";
        document.body.appendChild(vid);
        vid.play();
        vid.addEventListener("click", function() {
            vid.webkitEnterFullscreen();
        });
 };
```